# Angular 5 Spring Boot navigate directly to url

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to navigate directly to a url in my angular app using Spring Boot, however Spring just serves up the raw json response and never hits my app. Do I need to setup a redirect?

proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CollectionDatatableComponent } from 'app/datatable/collection/collection-datatable.component';
import { SearchDatatableComponent } from 'app/datatable/search/search-datatable.component';

const collectionRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'collection', component: CollectionDatatableComponent }
];

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SearchDatatableComponent },
    { path: 'collection/:id/_contents', component: CollectionDatatableComponent, children: collectionRoutes }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
```

WebController.java

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private FolderContentsService folderContentsService;

    @GetMapping(value="/cmt/collection/{id}/_contents", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<FolderContentDto>> getFolderContents(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception{
        List<FolderContentDto> contentEntityList = folderContentsService.getFolderContents(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(contentEntityList,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Result

```
[
{
id: "0901d63880504cab",
repositoryObjectName: "0b01d63880504b29",
repositoryType: "dcp_collection_structure",
modifiedDate: "1/16/2018 2:12:57 PM",
createdDate: "1/5/2018 3:49:52 PM",
size: "502"
},
{
id: "0b01d63880504bc9",
repositoryObjectName: "10 Guide Info",
repositoryType: "dcp_folder",
modifiedDate: "1/5/2018 3:12:04 PM",
createdDate: "1/5/2018 3:12:04 PM",
size: "0"
}
]
```